# How to load a text file from a class inside my EAR file?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, war, ear

I have a Java EE 5 project in Eclipse (actually, IBM RAD 7) running on WebSphere 7.

The workspace projects are laid out like this:

```
webapp <-- produces a WAR file
webappEAR <-- produces the EAR file
webappEJB <-- holds the Service and DAO classes
webappJPA <-- holds the domain/entity classes
webappTests <-- holds the JUnit tests
```

In one of my Service classes (in the webappEJB project) I need to load a text file as a resource.

I placed my text file in folder:

```
webappEAR/emailTemplates/myEmailTemplate.txt
```

So it appears in the EAR file here:

```
webappEAR.EAR
/emailTemplates/myEmailTemplate.txt
```

In my service class this is how I load it:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("emailTemplates/myEmailTemplate.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
/* and so on */
```

The problem is `input` is always null -- it can't find the resource.

I tried a leading slash (`"/emailTemplates/myEmailTemplate.txt"`) but that didn't work either.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Or a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: Have you tried with `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/emailTemplates/myEmailTemplate.txt");`?

Comment: @aymeric Yes, tried that.  Didn't work.  Should /emailTemplates be in the root of the EAR?  Is that the right location for this to work?

Comment: Oh... emailTemplates is not in your classpath (not under the root but in the war/WEB-INF/classes)? If not, it should...

Comment: Per default the EAR root folder is not in the classpath. Place the file in `webappEJB/src` or similar...

Answer (score 1):

The EAR file hierarchy/content is not on your classpath; Jar files packaged within your EAR file may be on a module's classpath, per configuration.

So package the resource into any of the JAR files already on the classpath of of the module containing your "service class".

It's not unreasonable to create a new JAR for resources, particularly if you'll be updating them independently.

Answer (score 0):

That code seems ok, in JBoss that works as a charm. It may happen that the class loader form the Thread class has a different classpath than the ear file.
Did you try using the same class you are coding to load the resource? 
Try something like this:

```
ClassInsideEar.class.getResourceAsStream("/emailTemplates/myEmailTemplate.txt");
```

You may also try placing the folder inside the war or jar (EJB) to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for loading resources from ear.
Path is folder/file. Location of file is resources/folder/file.

```
private InputStream loadContent(String path) {

    final String resourceName = path;
    final ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new PrivilegedExceptionAction<InputStream>() {
                    public InputStream run() throws IOException {
                        InputStream is = null;
                        URL url = classLoader.getResource(resourceName);
                        if (url != null) {
                            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                            if (connection != null) {
                                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                                is = connection.getInputStream();
                            }
                        }
                        return is;
                    }
                });
    } catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stream;
}
```